# How to design and implement a low-pass AR1 filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filters, lowpass-filter

I have a data series

```
y(n)
```

that I want to filter using a low-pass AR1 filter. I found that this filter has a transfer function

```
H=1/(1+s/omega_c)
```

with omega_c the cut-off frequency. [Error: this is not a discrete time filter.]

If I implement this in Matlab:

```
filter(1,[1 1/(2*pi*500)],y)
```

it does not give a correct result. Is there an error in my reasoning?

Comment: How did you go about discretising your transfer function to produce those coefficients?

Comment: @Speedy You mean that H(s) is in continuous time and I have to discretize it in order to be able to use it with a discrete time data series y(n)?

Comment: Exactly - I ask because you've presented your problem and attempted solution but not the reasoning you used to get there.

Comment: @Karlo Your `H` is written for continuous-time. Does it mean you want to design an analog filter? Isn't your data discrete?

Comment: @msm No, I want to design a digital filter. You are right, this is not a correct expression then.

Comment: @Karlo OK, I will give an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

An autoregressive filter is referred to as IIR (infinite impulse response) filter in signal processing.
 You have several options to do that. In Matlab, one way is to use commands like

```
[b,a] = butter(n,wn);             % Butterworth
[b,a] = cheby1(n,Rp,ws);          % Chebyshev Type I
[b,a] = cheby2(n,Rs,ws);          % Chebyshev Type II
[b,a] = ellip(n,Rp,Rs,ws);        % elliptic
```

where `wn` is the normalized cutoff, `ws` is normalized edge frequency, and `Rp` and `Rs` are the ripples of passband and stopband in dB (for more details see the documentation). Then use `filter` with the designed `a` and `b`.

---

If you want to design it yourself, your current analog filter can be a good starting point. You can use [bilinear transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_transform) to build your digital filter from an analog transfer function. Let's say your sampling period is $T$ (assume $T=1$ if it is just a series). Using this transform you should substitute $$s=\frac{2}{T}\frac{1-z^{-1}}{1+z^{-1}}\tag{1}$$
in the analog $H(s)$, to find the digital filter. One can show that the relationship between the cutoff frequency of the analog filter ($\omega_a$) and that of the digital filter ($\omega_d$) is $$\omega_a=\frac{2}{T}\tan\frac{\omega_d T}{2}\tag{2}$$
So if your desired digital filter's cutoff is $\omega_d (=2\pi f_d)$, then find the equivalent analog cutoff from $(2)$, and then your digital filter is just $H(s)$ with the given $s$ in $(1)$.

---

If you are strictly looking for a first order digital AR filter of the form $$H(z)=\frac{1-a}{1-az^{-1}}$$ then $$H(j\omega)=\frac{1-a}{1-ae^{-j\omega}}$$ and

$$|H(j\omega)|=\frac{1-a}{|1-ae^{-j\omega}|}=\frac{1-a}{|1-a\cos(\omega)+ja\sin(\omega)|}=\frac{1-a}{\sqrt{1-2a\cos(\omega)+a^2}}$$
With that, you can find $a$ with respect to the cutoff frequency.