# How to create an AR filter in Matlab

Tags: autoregressive-model

My goal is to replicate the procedure described on pages 15-16 (1461-1462) in this paper, prior to adaptive mixture ICA ([AMICA](https://sccn.ucsd.edu/~jason/amica_web.html)): [Overlearning in Marginal Distribution-Based ICA: Analysis and Solutions](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume4/sarela03a/sarela03a.pdf)

Using MATLAB,

- How do I estimate the AR-coefficient for a one-tap AR process?
- How do I remove the AR-process from the data? (The sample rate is 1000 Hz)
- Is there any basic literature, manual, or tutorial that you could recommend?

Comment: Maybe you find [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/35098/23301) useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering in reverse order,

For a tutorial, I recommend: (the all pole case is an AR model)

J. Makhoul, "Linear prediction: A tutorial review," in Proceedings of the IEEE, vol. 63, no. 4, pp. 561-580, April 1975.

doi: 10.1109/PROC.1975.9792

Abstract: This paper gives an exposition of linear prediction in the analysis of discrete signals. The signal is modeled as a linear combination of its past values and present and past values of a hypothetical input to a system whose output is the given signal. In the frequency domain, this is equivalent to modeling the signal spectrum by a pole-zero spectrum. The major part of the paper is devoted to all-pole models. The model parameters are obtained by a least squares analysis in the time domain. Two methods result, depending on whether the signal is assumed to be stationary or nonstationary. The same results are then derived in the frequency domain. The resulting spectral matching formulation allows for the modeling of selected portions of a spectrum, for arbitrary spectral shaping in the frequency domain, and for the modeling of continuous as well as discrete spectra. This also leads to a discussion of the advantages and disadvantages of the least squares error criterion. A spectral interpretation is given to the normalized minimum prediction error. Applications of the normalized error are given, including the determination of an "optimal" number of poles. The use of linear prediction in data compression is reviewed. For purposes of transmission, particular attention is given to the quantization and encoding of the reflection (or partial correlation) coefficients. Finally, a brief introduction to pole-zero modeling is given.
keywords: {Control theory;Econometrics;Frequency domain analysis;Information analysis;Predictive models;Rhythm;Signal analysis;Statistics;Time series analysis;Tutorial},
URL: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=1451722&isnumber=31191

How does one get rid of an AR process?

The inverse filter to an all pole filter, is a FIR filter using the AR coefficients.  Inverse filtering is my guess of what that means.

Question one,
There are a number of AR estimators in Matlab's Signal Processing tool box. You can look at those, or read the above paper and roll your own.  Essentially, you have to estimate the covariance of adjacent pairs of samples, and then use one of the methods detailed in the paper.  The term "one tap" might be confusing, [1 a0] might correspond to one tap or two, but [1] doesn't make sense while [1 a0] does.

Comment: This was a very helpful paper. For future reference, regarding [the various MATLAB options](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/functionlist.html): the Yule-Walker `aryule()` method [appears to be flawed compared to Burg's method](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.489.2674&rep=rep1&type=pdf) `arburg()`. There is a Yule-Walker recursive filter [`yulewalk()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/yulewalk.html), but there seems to be no equivalent Burg filter in the MATLAB Signal Processing Toolbox available. To clarify, I need to design a filter for the time-domain.

Comment: Try the community site. A ten second search returned from https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=✓&term=Burg  pwburg. There are likely to be more

Comment: I've read the paper now, but I am still having trouble understanding how to feed the parameters to a filter. (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327508/designing-an-all-pole-filter-based-on-autoregressive-ar-modelling-parameters)

Comment: >>help filter.     >>help conv

Comment: According to Wim can Drongelen an AR filter is of IIR type, so I am confused as to why you referred to a FIR filter. In my case, the signal is nonstationary but featuring "locally stationary processes" (Makhoul, 1975, p.564). The autocorrelation method then reduces to the covariance method (in the deterministic case), so I don't see why I would need to work with covariances?

Comment: Your original post asked how to remove the AR process.

Comment: I guess I need to read more about LTI systems before I can understand the application.

Comment: Here's my first attempt: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45327508/designing-an-all-pole-filter-based-on-autoregressive-ar-modelling-parameters